# why there is no return value rather gives null

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

why does the return value in this function gives None
rather i think it should return count

output - None

```
def longestChain(num,count):
    if num==1:
        return count
    elif num%2==0:
        num = num/2
        count+=1
        longestChain(num,count)
    elif num%2==1:
        num =3*num+1
        count+=1
        longestChain(num,count)

print(longestChain(13,1))
```

CORRECTED  ONE

```
def longestChain(num,count):
    if num==1:
        return count
    elif num%2==0:
        num = num/2
        count+=1
        return longestChain(num,count)
    elif num%2==1:
        num =3*num+1
        count+=1
        return longestChain(num,count)

print(longestChain(13,1))
```

Comment: Please make an [mcve]. I know it's a short program, but it would help you immensely to find the particular code that's causing the problem.

Comment: I notice you've tagged both Python 3 and 2.7 Which are you using? Asking cause the behaviour of division (i.e. `num/2`) is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only returning a value in case `num==1`. In the other cases, you are doing a recursive call, but you forgot to return a value there.

Comment: @iabhishek15 I think you should read up on how to use `return`. Then put a `return` statement into each of your three cases. Alternatively, define a variable, assign a value to that variable in all three cases, and return the value of that variable from a single statement at the end of the function.